# How do I configure a Shortcut to send URLs for Safari web pages?

Tags: safari, bug, shortcuts-app

Since updating to iOS 7, a Shortcut that had worked fine for years has stopped functioning as expected. The Shortcut is intend to mail the stuff I currently see to me. Since iOS 7, this continues to work, mailing pretty much exactly what I expect for a wide range or apps and content, but it has stopped working as expected (and as it did for years) when I use it for Safari web pages. At first (7.0) I got [occasional security warnings](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/16qa1at/privacy_settings_do_not_allow_shortcut_to_load/), though it would continue to send me URLs as expected for most pages, but since 7.1, it has stopped functioning: now I always get the entire content of the webpage, rather than the URL (as had been the case before).

[image]

How do I configure my Shortcut to send URLs for Safari (actually WebKit, I think) pages, without changing anything else about the Shortcut?

Comment: Still not fixed in 17.2!

Comment: What happens if you remove the „What‘s on screen“ part?

Comment: @nohillside Same. I've tried (and others have conformed) that even for a Shortcut that only receives URL WebKit (only) will send the entire webpage.

Comment: @nohillside Several people have reported this as a bug. My guess is that Shortcuts are being phased out or reworked (could just be my HyperCard trauma) so no existing bugs will be fixed.

Comment: Not sure it's a bug, it may be also just changed behaviour. Can't you just disable access to Web Content for the shortcut (edit shortcut, little i at the bottom, privacy tab)?

Comment: @nohillside There's no way to get a URL from a WebKit webpage. Changing the mapping or the permissions doesn't work (and results in errors for other sources). In effect WebKit (only) forces the full page into the input, no matter how the Shortcut is configured. Not sure how that would be "changed behavior".

Comment: Agreed, without changing the shortcut you won't be able to get the URL alone. But you could extract the URL from the input afterwards.

Comment: @nohillside There's no URL at all. Just the full content of the webpage, as plain text. Very broken.